# jQuery - datepicker repeats last day of the month

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using the jQuery UI datepicker and for some reason it repeats the last day of the month. For example, if the 31st falls on a Monday, Tue - Sat will all say 31 as well.

Here's an example: [Working example](http://lajollalasik.inseevstaging.com/)

The beginning of the month is fine.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in jQuery UI and there is no plan to fix it:
https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8953

"I don't think it's worth changing, but we'll accept patches if someone wants to prevent beforeShowDay from being invoked for days outside the current month when showOtherMonths is false (this would need to be introduced in a major release though)."

I think it is worth fixing - it is causing me issues and I don't know how to work around it.

It also only appears in Chrome. IE, Edge and Firefox seem ok.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hunter

Since there's no true fix for now, I did this:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar tr:last-child .ui-datepicker-other-month {
    display: none;
}
```

Not the most ideal solution, but it's fine visually.